# How can I access a Button on a fragment?

Tags: android, xml

How do I access a button that is on a fragment and program click events. I know there are similar questions to this, however I have tried the solutions they have given and they did not work for me. I always get the unreachable error.

Requirement; Basically I have two buttons in the XML, one is visible the other is not. I am trying to click on the visible button, making it invisible, then making the previously invisible one, visible.

Please note, the fragments are being made by editing Android Studios default navaigation drawer activity
I am trying to have a universal navigation drawer. Easier to edit the default class.

Activity Code

```
package co.timetrax.drawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting fragments
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fragment Code

```
package co.timetrax.drawer;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

}
```

Here is the fragment xml;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="co.timetrax.drawer.MainFragment">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MAIN"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/main_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/second_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You didn't set listener on the Buttons and also don't even have any code in `onClick` method.

Comment: That is the whole point of my question. I did set the listeners but they were  redflagged in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Change this method to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Button mainButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.main_button);
    //proceed to add the listener in a regular way
    //I will not write that code here; mainButton.setOnClickListener ......
    return view;

}
```

And do this for every `Button` or any other UI element you need.

Comment: I already tried this. when I go to write mainButton.setOnclickListener(this). the (this) is underlined red and the error is that its unreachable.

Comment: Its not working, trying it again. I must have done something wrong somewhere. But I have it written exactly as as the answer above.

Comment: Well I didn't include adding onClickListener since you can find that in a million other question. Or simply start typing `mainButton.setOn` and click enter. Haha, great. Have fun coding. Cheers bro. Do consider accepting the answer if it fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

You can call `getView()` anywhere in the fragment to get the root view. Then you can call:

```
View root = getView();
Button myButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id./*id*/);
myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: It's way better to just do that when inflating the view in `onCreateView` because `getView()` may return null, and this way you're secure from that.

Comment: Indeed, should have elaborated on that. Furthermore, calling `findViewById` less is better. But it's a thing that can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did actually try this and got the error Vucko has mentioned.

Comment: my Activity doesn't have an onCreateView or a call to Inflate.  but there are still fragments used.